# Send FlowOrchestrationEvent with EventPayload being outputs from lightning-flow component

Tags: lightning-web-components, standard-objects, platform-event

I have an LWC which renders flows in a lightning-flow component that belong to a Flow Orchestration Step.

Once they are completed I want to publish an Event to FlowOrchestrationEvent with the outputs produced from the flow. The outputs from lightning-flow look like so:

```
  {
    "dataType": "BOOLEAN",
    "name": "Escalation_Needed",
    "isCollection": false,
    "flowName": "Screening_Flow",
    "value": true,
    "objectType": null
  },
  {
    "dataType": "BOOLEAN",
    "name": "Screening_Completed",
    "isCollection": false,
    "flowName": "Screening_Flow",
    "value": true,
    "objectType": null
  }
]
```

The event when publishing rom the Work Guide is this

```
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "Jh2dLTfQormhirRWcEnwUg",
    "payload": {
      "OrchestrationInstanceId": "0jE0C0000004K3UUAU",
      "DoesCancelOrchestrationInstance": false,
      "CreatedById": "0050C000006N9cOQAS",
      "CreatedDate": "2023-05-26T10:55:20.612Z",
      "StepStatus": null,
      "StepInstanceId": "0jL0C0000004KPuUAM",
      "EventPayload": "rO0ABXNyABNqYXZhLnV0aWwuQXJyYXlMaXN0eIHSHZnHYZ0DAAFJAARzaXpleHAAAAACdwQAAAACc3IAL2NvbW1vbi5pbnZvY2F0aW9uLkludm9jYWJsZUFjdGlvbk91dHB1dFZhcmlhYmxlqgYnHMwwxEYCAAJMAAx2YXJpYWJsZU5hbWV0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMAA12YXJpYWJsZVZhbHVldAAWTGphdmEvaW8vU2VyaWFsaXphYmxlO3hwdAARRXNjYWxhdGlvbl9OZWVkZWRzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHABc3EAfgACdAATU2NyZWVuaW5nX0NvbXBsZXRlZHEAfgAIeA=="
    },
    "event": {
      "EventUuid": "6186d22b-3fb7-458c-b6fc-b1e9b040f677",
      "replayId": 3528565
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/FlowOrchestrationEvent"
}
```

As can be seen above the EventPayload are the fields encoded. When I put in the raw stringified input from the lightning-flow it breaks.

```
{
  "data": {
    "schema": "Jh2dLTfQormhirRWcEnwUg",
    "payload": {
      "OrchestrationInstanceId": "0jE0C0000004K4IUAU",
      "DoesCancelOrchestrationInstance": null,
      "CreatedById": "0050C000006N9cOQAS",
      "CreatedDate": "2023-05-26T13:48:49.519Z",
      "StepStatus": "Completed",
      "StepInstanceId": "0jL0C0000004KSFUA2",
      "EventPayload": "[{\"dataType\":\"BOOLEAN\",\"name\":\"Escalation_Needed\",\"isCollection\":false,\"flowName\":\"Screening_Flow\",\"value\":true,\"objectType\":null},{\"dataType\":\"BOOLEAN\",\"name\":\"Screening_Completed\",\"isCollection\":false,\"flowName\":\"Screening_Flow\",\"value\":true,\"objectType\":null}]"
    },
    "event": {
      "EventUuid": "327fd836-78f0-4908-9f40-05a5c6ff0cae",
      "replayId": 3528834
    }
  },
  "channel": "/event/FlowOrchestrationEvent"
}
```

I tried to encode it using the EncodingUtil but that didn't seem to work either.
Is there something I can do to encode the EventPayload to the format expected?